# foreach cannot operate on variables, cannot get enumerator, linkedlists

Tags: c#, foreach, linked-list, ienumerable, singly-linked-list

I have a simple program, we are busy with singly linked lists in my programming course, and I was experimenting by trying to count the amount of different types of objects, I have a class singlylinkedlist, App, Onceoff : App, Distrubuted : App, Cell

What I am trying to achieve is getting the type of object for each item in the singlylinkedlist called Developed and trying to determine with a "is" statement which type it is and incrementing the required counter, but the foreach is underlined with the following error 
"foreach cannot operate on variables of type 'PRr05.SinglyLinkedList' because 'PRr05.SinglyLinkedList' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumarator'", I am not exactly sure what this means but if I am correct, the Enumarator returns the Type, how can I fix this, SinglyLinkedList class underneath

(ps, yes this was a practical, but I am taking this a step further ;) )

**FOREACH METHOD**

```
public int countApps(char Type)
        {
            int countO = 0, countD = 0, countR = 0;
            foreach (App item in Developed)
            {
                if (item is Onceoff)
                {
                    countO++;
                }
                else
                    if (item is Distributed)
                    {
                        countD++;
                    }
                    else countR++;
            }

            if (Type == 'O')
            {
                return countO;
            }

            if (Type == 'D')
            {
                return countD;
            }

            if (Type == 'R')
            {
                return countR;
            }
        }
```

**SinglyLinkedList Class**

using System;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace Pr05
{
    public class SinglyLinkedList       // NO CHANGES PERMITTED TO EXISTING METHODS IN THIS CLASS


     {
            // Sentinel cell
            private int counter;
            private Cell head;   // pointer to first cell in the list
            public SinglyLinkedList() 
            {
                counter = 0;
                head = null;
            }
            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { get {return Current;}}
            object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }
            public int Count()  
            {
                return counter;
            }
            public Cell getFirst() 
            {
                return head;
            }
            public void addFirst(Object newItem) // Section Adding Cells at the Beginning pp 59 - 60
            /* pre:  Have object to be added to calling singly linked list object, which may be empty.
             * post: newItem is the element of the FIRST cell of the singly linked list.  All other existing cells of the
             *       singly linked list retain their ordering AFTER the new first cell.
             *       The counter is modified to reflect the addition of a new cell to the singly linked list. */
            {
                // ADD CODE FOR addFirst HERE
                Cell newCell = new Cell(newItem);
                newCell.setNext(head);
                head = newCell;
                counter++;
            }
            public void addLast(Object newItem) // Section Adding Cells at the End pp 60 - 61
            /* pre:  Have object to be added to calling singly linked list object, which may be empty.
             * post: newItem is the element of the LAST cell of the singly linked list.  All other existing cells of the
             *       singly linked list retain their ordering BEFORE the new last cell.
             *       The counter is modified to reflect the addition of a new cell to the singly linked list. 
             * CAREFUL: C# has certain restrictions which do not allow direct implemention of the code as specified in the 
             *          prescribed text.  Find a way around the restriction. */
            {
                // ADD CODE FOR addLast HERE
                if (this.Count() == 0)
                {
                    this.addFirst(newItem);
                    return;
                }
                Cell newCell = new Cell(newItem);
                Cell cur = head;
                while (cur.next() != null)
                    cur = cur.next();
                cur.setNext(newCell);
                counter++;
            }
            public Cell removeFirst()
            /* pre:  Have at least one cell in calling singly linked list object.
             * post: Return the cell removed, which is the first cell in the list.
             *       The counter is modified to reflect the removal of the first cell from the singly linked list. */
            {
                // ADD CODE FOR removeFirst HERE
                Cell cur = head;
                head = cur.next();
                cur.setNext(null);
                counter--;
                return cur;

            }
            public Cell removeLast()
            /* pre:  Have at least one cell in calling singly linked list object.
             * post: Return the cell removed, which is the last cell in the list.
             *       The counter is modified to reflect the removal of the last cell from the singly linked list. 
             * CAREFUL: C# has certain restrictions - find a way around the restriction. */
            {
                // ADD CODE FOR removeLast HERE
                Cell cur;
                if (this.Count() == 1)
                {
                    cur = head;
                    this.Clear();
                    return cur;
                }
                cur = head;
                Cell prev = head;
                while (cur.next() != null)
                {
                    prev = cur;
                    cur = cur.next();
                }
                prev.setNext(null);
                counter--;
                return cur;
             }
            public void addBefore(Object newItem, Cell link)
            /* pre:  Have object to be added to calling singly linked list object, and a link in the singly linked list BEFORE
             *       which the newItem's cell must be added.
             * post: newItem is the element of the added cell of the singly linked list.  All other existing cells of the
             *       singly linked list retain their ordering relevant to the position of the newly added cell.
             *       The counter is modified to reflect the addition of a new cell to the singly linked list. */
            {
                // ADD CODE FOR addBefore HERE
                if (link == null)  // list either empty or must be added at end of list
                {
                    this.addLast(newItem);
                    return;
                }
                Cell newCell = new Cell(newItem);
                Cell cur = head;
                if (cur == link)  // must be added as first cell
                {
                    this.addFirst(newItem);
                    return;
                }
                while (cur.next() != link)
                    cur = cur.next();
                cur.setNext(newCell);
                newCell.setNext(link);
                counter++;
            }
            public void addAfter(Object newItem, Cell link) // Section Inserting Cells After Other Cells pp 61 - 62
            /* pre:  Have object to be added to calling singly linked list object, and a link in the singly linked list AFTER
             *       which the newItem's cell must be added.
             * post: newItem is the element of the added cell of the singly linked list.  All other existing cells of the
             *       singly linked list retain their ordering relevant to the position of the newly added cell.
             *       The counter is modified to reflect the addition of a new cell to the singly linked list. */
            {
                // ADD CODE FOR addAfter HERE
                if (link == null)
                {
                    this.addLast(newItem);
                    return;
                }
                Cell newCell = new Cell(newItem);
                newCell.setNext(link.next());
                link.setNext(newCell);
                counter++;
            }
            public void Clear()
            /* pre:  Have calling singly linked list object, which could be empty.
             * post: EFFICIENTLY clear the singly linked list. */
            {
                // ADD CODE FOR Clear HERE
                counter = 0;
                head = null;
            }
            // OPTIONAL TASKS
            public Cell removeBefore(Cell link)
            /* pre:  Have at least one cell in calling singly linked list object. Have a link in the singly linked list.
             * post: Return the cell removed, which is the  cell BEFORE the given link.
             *       The counter is modified to reflect the removal of the cell from the singly linked list. */
            {
                // ADD CODE FOR removeBefore HERE
                if (link == head) // nothing to remove in front of link
                    return null;
                if (link == null) // then remove last cell
                    return removeLast();
                Cell cur = head;
                Cell prev = head;
                while (cur.next() != link)
                {
                    prev = cur;
                    cur = cur.next();
                }
                if (cur == head)
                    return removeFirst();
                prev.setNext(link);
                cur.setNext(null);
                counter--;
                return cur;
            }
            public Cell removeAfter(Cell link) // Section Deleting Cells pp 62 - 63
            /* pre:  Have at least one cell in calling singly linked list object. Have a link in the singly linked list.
             * post: Return the cell removed, which is the  cell AFTER the given link.
             *       The counter is modified to reflect the removal of the cell from the singly linked list. */
            {
                // ADD CODE FOR removeAfter HERE
                if (link == null)   // nothing after
                    return null;
                if (link.next() == null) // then nothing after link
                    return null;
                Cell cur = link.next();
                link.setNext(cur.next());
                cur.setNext(null);
                counter--;
                return cur;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming `Developed` is a class, rather than a `Collection`.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `Developed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some essential fundamental changes both in the syntax and the concept of your code. For example, first you should know that `foreach` is only used with the objects that implement `System.Collections.IEnumberable` or `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<T>`. There is a twist here; if you want to iterate over your `Developed` class's (maybe) members, you should use reflection; if you want to facilitate your `Developed` class to be usable with `foreach` statement, you must derive from one of the two first `BCL` classes I've mentioned. Please consider revising your code.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the "...you should use reflection;..." part, how do you mean reflection?

Comment: By reflection, I meant the operations you could establish with System.Reflection namespace's type. Typically, Reflection is a solid way to solicit information from types, modules, methods, and so on. On your very code, for example, if you wanted to ONLY get the properties' identifier name, you could have used this way: foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo item in typeof(Developed).GetProperties()) { ...your code..... }